# How to detect "light" colors with PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a dynamic store project and I use a loop to print all color options for a product as color boxes, however I really need to add a "border" to these colors which are light. I tried something like the following but It is very limited, it is actually limited to white color only, it won't catch something like #ddd, #eea... etc

Here is my loop:

```
foreach($colors as $color) {
    $color = trim($color);
    if (!empty($color)) {
        if (in_array($color, array('white','White','#fff','#FFF','#FFFFFF','#ffffff'))) {
            $bordercolor = '#bbb';
        } else {
            $bordercolor = $color;
        }
    }
}
```

Colors is an array from backend like: White, #000, #cc0000, etc. It is not practical to add all exceptions in the if/else condition too, any quick idea?

Comment: Google for `RGB TO HSV(HSL)` - Hue Saturation Value (Lightness). Higher lightness value is more lighter colour.

Comment: This question could help you: [RGB to HSV in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1773698/112968). You can then simply check for values of V above a certain threshold.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614011/intelligent-color-detection check this

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Transform HTML colour to RGB, then to Hue-Saturation-Lightnes (HSV)

```
<?php

function HTMLToRGB($htmlCode)
  {
    if($htmlCode[0] == '#')
      $htmlCode = substr($htmlCode, 1);

    if (strlen($htmlCode) == 3)
    {
      $htmlCode = $htmlCode[0] . $htmlCode[0] . $htmlCode[1] . $htmlCode[1] . $htmlCode[2] . $htmlCode[2];
    }

    $r = hexdec($htmlCode[0] . $htmlCode[1]);
    $g = hexdec($htmlCode[2] . $htmlCode[3]);
    $b = hexdec($htmlCode[4] . $htmlCode[5]);

    return $b + ($g << 0x8) + ($r << 0x10);
  }

function RGBToHSL($RGB) {
    $r = 0xFF & ($RGB >> 0x10);
    $g = 0xFF & ($RGB >> 0x8);
    $b = 0xFF & $RGB;

    $r = ((float)$r) / 255.0;
    $g = ((float)$g) / 255.0;
    $b = ((float)$b) / 255.0;

    $maxC = max($r, $g, $b);
    $minC = min($r, $g, $b);

    $l = ($maxC + $minC) / 2.0;

    if($maxC == $minC)
    {
      $s = 0;
      $h = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      if($l < .5)
      {
        $s = ($maxC - $minC) / ($maxC + $minC);
      }
      else
      {
        $s = ($maxC - $minC) / (2.0 - $maxC - $minC);
      }
      if($r == $maxC)
        $h = ($g - $b) / ($maxC - $minC);
      if($g == $maxC)
        $h = 2.0 + ($b - $r) / ($maxC - $minC);
      if($b == $maxC)
        $h = 4.0 + ($r - $g) / ($maxC - $minC);

      $h = $h / 6.0; 
    }

    $h = (int)round(255.0 * $h);
    $s = (int)round(255.0 * $s);
    $l = (int)round(255.0 * $l);

    return (object) Array('hue' => $h, 'saturation' => $s, 'lightness' => $l);
  }

$colour = '#F12346';
$rgb = HTMLToRGB($colour);
$hsl = RGBToHSL($rgb);

var_dump($hsl);
```

Usage:

```
$colour = '#F12346';
$rgb = HTMLToRGB($colour);
$hsl = RGBToHSL($rgb);
if($hsl->lightness > 200) {
  // this is light colour!
}
```

Source:

- http://www.caperna.org/computing/repository/hsl-rgb-color-conversion-php

Demo:

- http://codepad.org/X7KV4n4n

Comment: there's potential for optimizing this fancy solution. i.e. #FFFC00 (shiny yellow) won't be detected as a light color above 150

Comment: This one worked best for me. I liked the simplicity of the one at https://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast, but it didn't always give the desired results. Thank you.

Comment: How would you incorporate transparency in a RGBa value? e.g. rgba(53, 52, 72, 0.5)

Answer (score 14):

What I'd do in this situation is detect the lightness of the color using [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), and compare that against a certain percentage. For example, the lightness attribute in the HSL algorithm takes the chroma (M - m where M is the largest RGB value and m is the smallest RGB value) and divides that by 2.

```
function lightness($R = 255, $G = 255, $B = 255) {
    return (max($R, $G, $B) + min($R, $G, $B)) / 510.0; // HSL algorithm
}
```

The above function would return a percentage of how light the color you've selected is (simple hex -> rgb conversions are required for this also, but that should be pretty easy). The reason I divided by 510 instead of 2 is because in order to get the percentage *after* dividing by 2, you divide by 255. To make it faster you can simply say: `(x / 2) / 255 = x / 510`. Then I'd compare the value returned by the above function to, say, 80%.

```
$r = hexdec($hex[0].$hex[1]);
$g = hexdec($hex[2].$hex[3]);
$b = hexdec($hex[4].$hex[5]);

if(lightness($r, $g, $b) >= .8) {
    // add border
} else {
    // no border
}
```

Comment: Great solution. Just wanted to point out for others that the `$hex` value shouldn't have the `#`; for example: `$hex = 'aaaaaa';`;

Comment: Great solution indeed!

Answer (score 9):

In addition to other formulas given by other answers, you may want to consider [Luma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_(video)).

```
function luma($r, $g, $b)
{
  return (0.2126 * $r + 0.7152 * $g + 0.0722 * $b) / 255;
}

$l = luma(0, 15, 255);
```

Values closer to 0 will be darker. Values closer to 1 will be lighter.

Answer (score 6):

Short way if you have RGB color as hexadecimal string:

```
$hexRGB = "4488BB";
if(hexdec(substr($hexRGB,0,2))+hexdec(substr($hexRGB,2,2))+hexdec(substr($hexRGB,4,2))> 381){
    //bright color
}else{
    //dark color
}
```

**Note**: The thereshold 381 is the sum of the values at average level. If you want the thereshold to be lighter or darker, upper or lower 381 in the range 1 - 765.

Comment: So short but effective.

Answer (score 2):

There also is a simpler way with even less code:

```
<?php
//Functions

function getRGB($colorCode) {
    //Turn html color code into RGB
    $var_R = substr($colorCode, 0, 2);
    $var_G = substr($colorCode, 2, 2);
    $var_B = substr($colorCode, 4, 2);  

    //Get Hex values
    $val_R = hexdec($var_R);
    $val_G = hexdec($var_G);
    $val_B = hexdec($var_B);

    //Red is seen as light too, gets fixed with this
    $remRed = hexdec('99');
    if ($val_R > $remRed) {
        $RGB = $val_G.' '.$val_B;
    } else {
        $RGB = $val_R.' '.$val_G.' '.$val_B;
    }

    return $RGB;
}

function getHSL($R = 255, $G = 255, $B = 255) {
    $hsl = (max($R, $G, $B) + min($R, $G, $B)) / 510.0;
    return $hsl;
}
?>
```

Now the calling:

```
$color = 0000FF; //Blue
$RGBcode = getRGB($color); //Returns 0 0 255
$RGBcode = str_replace(' ', ', ', $RGBcode); //Replaces an empty space with a ,
$val_HSL = getHSL($RGBcode); //Returns value from 0.5 to 1
if ($val_HSL >= 0.8) {
    //Reject color
} else {
    //Accept Color
    $color = '#'.$color; //Sets it to html: #0000FF
}
```

Comment: This worked the best for my purposes. `if ($val_HSL < 0.5)` seems to translate to "darker color".

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a short derived version from @Luca C.’s answer for colors in HEX format (e.g. #FFFFFF or #FFF)

```php
<?php 
function isDark($hex){
    $average = 381; // range 1 - 765
    if(strlen(trim($hex)) == 4){
        $hex = "#" . substr($hex,1,1) . substr($hex,1,1) . substr($hex,2,1) . substr($hex,2,1) . substr($hex,3,1) . substr($hex,3,1);
    }
    return ((hexdec(substr($hex,1,2))+hexdec(substr($hex,3,2))+hexdec(substr($hex,5,2)) < $average) ? true : false);
}

var_dump( isDark("#000000") ); // bool(true)

?>
```