# VirtualTreeView and VCL Styles

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, vcl-styles

i'm using VirtualTreeView (as a grid - in Delphi XE7) in my app and i also chose to use the Carbon VCL style.
The problem arise because i need to color some rows according some status on each line, and the font color keep staying white even when i use a light color on a line. So it is impossible to read the data. When i use the Iceberg Classico style, this issue do not occurs.

So basically, i can change my set of rows color according to the style selected, it is one solution. But i'm looking for a way to modify the font color according to the row color background?

I'm doing the colorization code inside the event: BeforeCellPaint and i tried to modify the font color without any success.

Any idea?

Comment: Please post your colorization code.

Comment: Btw, i found a library that helps a lot on this subject:

// unit for the VCL Styles Utils
// https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils/

TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := aColor;
if TStyleManager.ActiveStyle.Name = 'Carbon' then            TCustomStyleExt(TStyleManager.ActiveStyle).SetStyleFontColor(sfTreeItemTextNormal, clBlack)
else                  TCustomStyleExt(TStyleManager.ActiveStyle).SetStyleFontColor(sfTreeItemTextNormal, aFontColor);

TargetCanvas.FillRect(CellRect);

With this i can change the font color.

Comment: Post that as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

i found a library that helps a lot on this subject:

```
// unit for the VCL Styles Utils 
// github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils 

TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := aColor; 
if TStyleManager.ActiveStyle.Name = 'Carbon' then
   TCustomStyleExt(TStyleManager.ActiveStyle).SetStyleFontColor(sfTreeItemTextNorma‌​l, clBlack) 
else
   TCustomStyleExt(TStyleManager.ActiveStyle).SetStyleFontColor(sfTreeItemTextNorma‌​l, aFontColor); 
TargetCanvas.FillRect(CellRect);
```

With this i can change the font color.

Laurent

Comment: See this question for an algorithm for choosing light or dark font color based on background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855884/determine-font-color-based-on-background-color