# How to change label forecolour based on the background

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, window

ie. if the background is white the label textcolour should be white and vice versa

im using the following code bgDelta is always 0 and the colour varies but in case of white background the label colour is also white.

```
public Color IdealTextColor(Color bg)
   {
       int nThreshold = 105;
       int bgDelta = Convert.ToInt32((bg.R * 0.299) + (bg.G * 0.587) + (bg.B * 0.114));
       Color fColor = (105 - bgDelta < nThreshold) ? Color.Black : Color.White;
       return fColor;
   }
```

Comment: hello unlucky please let me know it there is any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I debug I got it black;

```
//bg.R=255, bg.G=255, bg.B=255
bgDelta=76.245 + 149.685 + 29.07= 255
105 - bgDelta=-150
result=Color.Black
```

Code;

```
IdealTextColor(Color.White);
...
public Color IdealTextColor(Color bg){
int nThreshold = 105;
int bgDelta = Convert.ToInt32((bg.R * 0.299) + (bg.G * 0.587) + (bg.B * 0.114));
Color fColor = (105 - bgDelta < nThreshold) ? Color.Black : Color.White;
return fColor;}
```

Better Approach;

```
double fcolor = 1 - ( 0.299 * color.R + 0.587 * color.G + 0.114 * color.B)/255;
```

Comment: the fact is the bgdelta is always 0 and u would only get black

Comment: You could use different algorithm: [Determine font color based on background color](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1855903/3060520)

Answer (score 0):

```
lable.ForeColor = form.BackColor
```

Comment: i meant not to back color based on back color