# Algorithm to create very distinct, eye catching color from the background

Tags: colors

every one.

I am looking for good algorithm to generate very distinct, eye catching color for specific area of background, so that the object in the area will have quite different very visible color than the background.

Black for bright bg, and White for dark bg is not an option here.
I like to get very eye catching color for human eyes, emitting color.

For example, for black background, I d rather green or yellow color to be retrieved, as this color is much better than simple white color.

I tried to inverse the average color of the area, but it s not so much clear visually.

Please give me good idea if you have.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine font color based on background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855884/determine-font-color-based-on-background-color)

Comment: I do not want just simple black or white color, as I stated on the post.

Comment: @PeterO. do you have any good solution for this problem?