# How to auto change background on flutter

Tags: flutter, background, carousel

i was new on flutter coding and i'm still learning, i tried to coding the design i found in internet but now i'm stuck on how to make background change depend on what image in front of it.
the front image is like using carousel slider so it will change the image when i slide so i want make change it change the background image too corresponding the front image

here my source code:

```
class _MainCafeProfileState extends State<MainCafeProfile> {
  int _current = 0;
  final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();
  final List<Widget> ImgList = [
    HeaderCafeProfileWidget(imageUrl: 'assets/images/images_equipment_1.png'),
    HeaderCafeProfileWidget(imageUrl: 'assets/images/images_equipment_2.png'),
    HeaderCafeProfileWidget(imageUrl: 'assets/images/images_equipment_1.png'),
  ];
  @override
  Widget HeaderImageCard() {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              CarouselSlider(
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  initialPage: 0,
                  enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                  viewportFraction: 1,
                  height: 280,
                  onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                    setState(() {
                      _current = index;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                items: ImgList,
              ),
              // SLIDER INDICATOR
              Container(
                transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, -40, 0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: ImgList.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => _controller.animateToPage(entry.key),
                      child: Container(
                        width: _current == entry.key ? 18 : 4,
                        height: 4,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 4.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: whiteColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(2),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: whiteColor,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 297,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/images_equipment_1.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                sigmaX: 5,
                sigmaY: 5,
              ),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Neutral10.withOpacity(0.2),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                // HeaderCafeProfile(),
                HeaderImageCard(),
                TitleCafeProfile(
                  title: 'Rivarno Kopi',
                  rating: 4.8,
                  price: '\$\$',
                ),
                MainContent(),
                ReviewCafeProfile(
                  imageUrl: 'assets/images/1.jpg',
                  title: 'A Review: Ancala Coffee & Bistro',
                  desc:
                      'Description container, where you can spoil about the review',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          BackButtonWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[[image: the current program image]]

i was try making the background change depend on the image front of it, so when the front image was slide the background image will change to
[[image: first image]]
[[image: sencond image but the background image still not change]]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functionality of computeLuminance ([Reference Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909746/how-to-check-brightness-of-a-background-color-to-decide-text-color-written-on-it))

Or either,
Check this package [Palette Generator](https://pub.dev/packages/palette_generator)