# Detect optimal position for text

Tags: c++, winapi, drawing, direct2d

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855884/determine-font-color-based-on-background-color) I am able to determine what color the text should be,  given a background.

When I have a background image, I take all the pixels that are under the text and, for each pixel, I calculate the optimal color, black  or white. If I have more blacks, the text is drawn in black, else white.

Using for example the IWICBitmap lock:

```
    UINT bs0 = 0, bs1 = 0;
    WICInProcPointer ptr0 = 0, ptr1 = 0;
    l0->GetDataPointer(&bs0, &ptr0);
    l1->GetDataPointer(&bs1, &ptr1);
    DWORD* pc0 = (DWORD*)ptr0;
    DWORD* pc1 = (DWORD*)ptr1;

    int whites = 0;
    int blacks = 0;
    for (int yy = 0; yy < (int)Height(); yy++)
    {
        for (int xx = 0; xx < (int)Width() ; xx++)
        {
            DWORD& w0 = pc0[yy * (int)Width() + xx];
            DWORD& w1 = pc1[yy * (int)Width() + xx];

            if (w1 == 0) // not under the text
                continue;
            
            unsigned char* pCurrPixel = (unsigned char*)&w0;
            float red = pCurrPixel[0]/255.0f;
            float green = pCurrPixel[1] / 255.0f;
            float blue = pCurrPixel[2] / 255.0f;
            float alpha = pCurrPixel[3] / 255.0f;

            auto cx = ContrastColor({ red,green,blue,alpha }, 1.0f);
            if (cx.r > 0.5f)
                whites++;
            else
                blacks++;
            nop();
        }
    }
    if (whites > blacks)
    {
        // This better be white
        Col = { 1,1,1,1 };
    }
    else
    {
        // This better be black
        Col = { 0,0,0,1 };
    }
```

Now this of course will have some problems if the difference between blacks and whites are small. So I'm now trying to find, in the image a better position for the text.

For example, in the image here, the text is better in top right, than in the center.

[image]

The question is how to find the optimal text position. I could of course loop the entire image (based on the frame rect of the text) and determine the position that has the bigger difference between blacks and whites.

But, is there a quicker way?

Comment: *"how to find the optimal text position"* - By finding a robust definition of what *"good"* is and running a maximization algorithm against this formula. That's a difficult problem to solve, and you might be well advised to hand this off to some shape of AI.

Comment: Divide the image into blocks that are half the size that you need for your text, calculate the average brightness of all of them and pick the brightest (or darkest). Or just draw your text with a dropshadow.

Comment: If you're willing to put the text anywhere, then why don't you put it somewhere you want, and compute its foreground color afterwards, from the surrounding pixels only? Otherwise for scanning a screen since you're coding near the GPU you can use a compute shader and benefit from its massive multithreading since the process you're after seems to be parallelizable. I think you can also share a texture between DirectX (maybe not Direct2D, as its underlying objects are not exposed...) and the compute shader (this need to be checked) to avoid CPU <=> GPU transfers when possible

Comment: @SimonMourier the point is also to detect a good place to put the text automatically. Actually I'm doing it all in the CPU atm, it's not scanning the entire screen but a small preview so it's not slow.

Comment: It could be easy for humans to detect a good place to put the text. You can randomly select some pieces of pixels and detect a good place in them.