# JAVA - swing - draw/fill with invert/negated colors of destination canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas

I cannot find any info on how to draw shapes on a graphic canvas, making sure what I draw is not the same color as the background

there are some solutions out there but they all use images drawing only with per pixel operations/loops or filters; I also tried different Composite operations, but none suit what I want

so lets say I do

```
g.setColor(color.white) // relevant in this case ? not sure
g.fillRect(...)
```

I want the rectangle to be in inverted colors of the background so it is always visible

sorry I cant provide more code, I really dont know how to achieve this

thanks

Comment: Just as a side note you should not use Canvas in a swing application. Canvas is part of the AWT which is a heavyweight toolkit Swing is a lightweight toolkit and the two usually should not be mixed. I would strongly recommend replacing your Canvas with a JPanel.

Comment: "I cannot find any info on how to draw shapes on a graphic canvas, making sure what I draw is not the same color as the background": oh yeah??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your paint method could retrieve the current color, and search for its complementary color:

```
        Color originalColor = g.getColor();

        g.setColor(complementaryColor(originalColor));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

The `complementaryColor` method is inspired from this topic : [Reverse opposing colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672271/reverse-opposing-colors)

```
Color complementaryColor(final Color bgColor) {

    Color complement = new Color(255 - bgColor.getRed(),
            255 - bgColor.getGreen(),
            255 - bgColor.getBlue());

    return complement;
}
```