# How to tell if an image is light or dark using ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to tell if an image is light or dark in ruby?

The use case is as a user uploads an image, the application (e.g. the controller in a rails app) could automatically detect whether an image is light or dark and record that result so the view can place the image on an appropriate background for maximal contrast.

I found similar answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52506830/5783745) for python and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265041/detect-if-image-is-mostly-dark-or-light-in-javascript) for javascript, but couldn't spot the equivalent in ruby

Comment: How do you define "light" and "dark" images?

Comment: @Stefan in my use case I have some dark backgrounds and light backgrounds and want to try to give lighter images the darker backgrounds and vice versa. I had no preconceived way of defining which are light and which are dark though.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you want to work with images in Ruby the usual go to gem is [RMagick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick) which works on top of ImageMagick. This [article](https://www.atlantbh.com/how_to_detect_colour_brightness_in_ruby/) might help you with what you need in terms of how to achieve it with RMagick or you can create your own version of a solution.