# how do i find the brightness of pixels on an image using a line profile

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, line, brightness

I'm trying to find the brightness of pixels along a horizontal line across an image but I'm stuck on how to get either an array of numbers or maybe using a loop to change the x values and output the values of the pixels so I can calculate the brightness of each and then I can average across that line. This is what I got so far:

```
from PIL import Image
from math import sqrt
import os 
image = Image.open(os.path.join("mypath", "a.jpg"))
import numpy as np
image = imag.convert ('RGB')
X,Y = (137, 137) #this is where i dont know what else to add
pixelRGB = imag.getpixel((X,Y))
R,G,B = pixelRGB
brightness =([R,G,B])/3
print(brightness)
```

I don't know how to add a loop.

Comment: Do you know how to write a program that uses a loop to print the numbers from 0 to 99?

Comment: Something went wrong on copy/paste from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6449381/2834978) . `brightness =sum([R,G,B])/3`

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate from 0 to `width` with a loop:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("1.png")
width, height = image.size
y = 137

brightness_values = []

# Loop through the horizontal line
for x in range(width):
    pixelRGB = image.getpixel((x, y))
    R, G, B = pixelRGB
    brightness = (R + G + B) / 3  
    brightness_values.append(brightness)

print(brightness_values)

average_brightness = sum(brightness_values) / len(brightness_values)
print(f"Average brightness: {average_brightness}")
```

Comment: There's no real need to store all the brightness values in a list because, as your formula in the second to last line shows, you only need the sum... which you can accumulate in a single variable and save RAM and time.

Answer (score 0):

Processing images with `for` loops in Python is slow and error-prone. Try to use Pillow's built-in functions or vectorised Numpy functions instead.

---

Firstly, using Pillow:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageStat

# Create 256x256 image whose rows will have different means depending on the y-value
im = Image.radial_gradient('L').convert('RGB')
```

[image]

```
# Crop out row 64
row64 = im.crop((0,64,im.width,65))

# Get statistics for that row
stats = ImageStat.Stat(row64)

# Print means
print(stats.mean)
```

**Output:**

```
[133.3984375, 133.3984375, 133.3984375]
```

---

And secondly using Numpy:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Create 256x256 image whose rows will have different means depending on the y-value
im = Image.radial_gradient('L').convert('RGB')
```

[image]

```
# Convert to Numpy array
na = np.array(im)

# print mean of row 0, row 64 and row 128
print(np.mean(na[0]), np.mean(na[64]), np.mean(na[128]))
```

Printed values:

```
207.3203125 133.3984375 90.01171875
```

---

If you should wish to calculate the mean (or a line profile) along ***any*** line, not necessarily vertical or horizontal, you can use `scikit-image`.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from skimage.draw import line

# Create 256x256 image whose rows will have different means depending on the y-value
im = Image.radial_gradient('L').convert('RGB')
```

[image]

```
# Convert to Numpy array
na = np.array(im)

# Get row/column coordinates of diagonal line from top-left to bottom-right
rr, cc = line(0,0, 255,255)

# Get means of points along diagonal
result = np.mean(na[rr,cc])
```