# Sorting Hex Colors using C#

Tags: sorting, colors, drop-down-menu, hex

Im working on an MVC 3.0 application using C# code.
I have a "Color" table related to "Products" table. 
The value of each color which is hexadecimal (for example #FFFFFF) is saved in a nvarchar field "value". 
In my products client section, I have a DropDownList for colors of a specific product. 
So I need to sort these colors in the dropDownList from lighter to darker... 
Any help will be appreciated... :)

Comment: Lots of useful information here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the hex code into a number, create a color from it, and get its brightness:

```
.OrderBy(c => Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(c.Substring(1), 16)).GetBrightness())
```