# Increasing luminous of a Color in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using this code to randomly change the color of my textView. I have a black background so sometimes these colors are hard to read.

```
 int r = (rand.nextInt(176) * 80 ) / 256;
        int g = (rand.nextInt(176) * 80 ) / 256;
        int b = (rand.nextInt(176) * 80 ) / 256;

        TextView pos = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.position);
        pos.setText(((Integer)(position + 1)).toString());
        pos.setTextSize(30);
        pos.setTextColor(Color.argb(255,r,g,b));

        TextView data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textOfTip);
        data.setText(tipsList[position].toString());
        data.setTextSize(24);
        data.setTextColor(Color.argb(255,r,g,b));
```

My question is, how can i increase the brightness or luminous effect of the text color so they can read easily.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get your color in the format `0xAARRGGBB` (example, solid red is 0xFFFF0000). Then, push it to the method [`colorToHSV`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#colorToHSV%28int,%20float%5b%5d%29). Next, change the [L/V/B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brightness) value (which [vary slightly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), but I think will be close enough for what you're doing). Lastly, call [`HSVToColor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#HSVToColor%28float%5b%5d%29) to get your new color in `0xAARRGGBB` format again. There are then [several ways](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=android+hex+to+argb) to convert this to R,G,B values, which usually involve byte shifting.

Something like this:

```
int color = 0xFFFF0000;
float[] hsv = new float[3];
Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
hsv[2] = 0.2f;
color = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
int[] rgb = new int[3];
MyColor.colorToRGB(color, rgb); // Your custom method
// The rgb array now contains your RGB colors.
```

*Note*: There is also [`RGBToHSV`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#RGBToHSV%28int,%20int,%20int,%20float%5b%5d%29), which may come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some formulae for acheiving the brightness and luminous effct.This article gives you good understanding about it.

[Formula to determine brightness of RGB color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color)