# Combine RGB colors from several images

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, colors, rgb

I've several images with different color values, each value is 8-bit value.
Every image represents the same frame. I'm trying to sum all images together to get a better picture.
I've tried combining the colors using the average of the colors, however the combined picture is too dark.
Is there a known algorithm that combines the colors?

Thanks

Comment: Averaging should have worked, if you're treating the R,G,B channels separately. Care to share some code?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to make a greyscale image out of several colour channels. While averaging might work, one standard method is to use *[log-average luminance](http://www.cacs.louisiana.edu/~cice/lal/index.html)*:

```
gray_pixel = 0.27*red + 0.67*green + 0.06*blue
```

Note that all methods like this try to produce *perceived* luminance of each colour based on how the average human eye sees images. There are many other constants that produce similar results - see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/596243/679081) for more info on objective and perceived brightness.

Answer (score 0):

If the photos are geometrically calibrated (i.e. the camera and the scene were not changed between shots), simply average the value value of each pixel across all images. This will reduce noise, and will keep your result in color.

Answer (score 0):

You have to average colors of each pixel corresponding to each other. Just sum images to each other and then element-wise divide it by number of images. If you want to take some area from one image and others from other you have to slice your matrices and then fill its values to new empty array or array of zeros.