# Given hue and saturation of a color, how to generate colors in evenly spaced relative luminance level?

Tags: algorithm, colors, hsv, hsl, luminance

Given hue and saturation of a color (H & S of HSL), how to generate colors in evenly spaced relative luminance level?  E.g.

[image: Linear by Luminance screencap]
Source: http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-schemer-01.htm

If I give it a pure Red @ 50 relative luminance, how can I mathematically generate RED at different relative luminance in 5 - 10 stops?

Comment: Well, it's no exactly an algorithm, [but this pretty much explains what it's doing](http://www.workwithcolor.com/color-luminance-2233.htm), with those percentages you can probably work something out. Also [see this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color).

Comment: @Wrikken actually I cannot figure out the Luminance %.  I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689952/how-to-determine-luminance-from-rgb

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is a dumb linear search from 0 to 100 in L of HSL and stop when it reaches one of the Lum stops.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of interesting things may be found in sources of [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), which has some built-in color-calculating functions, listed [here](http://lesscss.org/#reference) (search for 'rgb', that will be the first one).

Going to implementation, take a look for their [one-liner](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/dist/less-1.5.0.js#L2835) for `luma` function, which should return luminance of a color.

Comment: Thanks, I read the code but it's pretty simplistic because it only manipulates the `L` value in HSL space which does not scale linearly with relative luminance.  It does the same thing as "Linear by Lightness" in workwithcolor.com

Comment: But it also contains calculation formula for luminance. What more do you need?

Comment: I need a way to figure out how to generate a number of shades of the same hue & saturation by evenly spaced relative luminance.