# sorting color selections on brightness

Tags: php, css, sorting, colors, rgb

Let's see, i give you a little background about my question.
I am a airbrush guy that love to paint with these kind of things. BUT i airbrush RC car body's that i have to paint from the inside out. This means that i paint the colors in reverse so first the dark colors and finishing with white.

Now, when my customers have selected their colors (from dropdown boxes) in which they want me to paint the designs, i have to sort them myself from dark to light. With two colors it is easy but more then 7 colors it is beginning to get hard.

So what i need is this;
I need a php script that sort the colors (currently in rgb) in painting order (dark to light). I have googled around but i didn't find that usefull one and i hope you guy's can help me with this.

Comment: More generally, to handle colors in a good way (nearer from the human perceived way), you have to change color space (see HSL, HSB, etc.)

Comment: yeah i know, i saw this question also but the answer, i don't get it at all. So after a few of these posts that i found i decided to post my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a group of functions (`usort(), uasort(), uksort()`) that allow you to sort arrays using compare functions. So if you take one of the formulas from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color), you can use the value to sort the array.

```
$colors = array(
  '#000000',
  '#FF0000',
  '#00FF00',
  '#0000FF',
  '#FFFF00',
  '#00FFFF',
  '#FF00FF',
  '#C0C0C0',
  '#FFFFFF'
);

function colorToLum($color) {
  $red = hexdec(substr($color, 1, 2));
  $green = hexdec(substr($color, 3, 2));
  $blue = hexdec(substr($color, 5, 2));
  return (0.299 * $red + 0.587 * $green + 0.114 * $blue);
}

usort(
  $colors,
  function ($one, $two) {
    return colorToLum($one) - colorToLum($two);
  }
);

var_dump($colors);
```

Comment: Cool, i will work this out and see if this is the script i need... i'll be back.

Comment: Thomas,
I have modified it in a way to see actually the colors.


If i would translate it to the brushing it must be;
1-black
2-blue
3-red
4-yellow
5-GRAY
6-white
because if i paint yellow on top of gray you will see the yellow.

Comment: Thomas i have tried it with recent paintjobs and putted the colors into the script and it seems that it is after all pretty accurate.
See this : http://airbrush.mrdracing.nl/gallery_images/14/perry05.jpg
This is what i'm talking about.

Comment: Those are not the correct coefficients for sRGB, and there's no linearizing—the colors need to be linearized first.  You need to linear eyes, apply coefficients, and then convert to a perceptual lightness space if you want to sort based on perceived lightness.  See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56237498/10315269

Answer (score 0):

The very [first result on google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php%20sort%20color%20light%20dark&oq=php%20sort%20color%20light%20dark&aqs=chrome..69i57.6804j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) turned up this on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/alexkingorg/2158428).

It looks like you should be able to use it for your purposes.

Comment: Hi, yeah well i've tried it but it was not as accurate as the script from Thomas, sorry. Thank you for your reply.