# Convert a color image to grayscale in MATLAB without rgb2gray

Tags: matlab, image-processing, grayscale

I want convert my color image to grayscale and avoid to use `rgb2gray` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So then:

```
I_grey = mean(I_colour, 3);
```

It's possible you then might need to cast it to a `uint8` before you can view it:

```
I_grey = uint8(mean(I_colour, 3));
```

Or if you want to be really accurate you should actually be finding a weighted average. See the answer to this question for weighting options: [Formula to determine brightness of RGB color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color)

Here is an example of this:

```
W = permute([0.3086, 0.6094, 0.0820], [3,1,2]);
I_grey = uint8(sum(bsxfun(@times, double(I_colour), W),3));
```

Comment: I'm new in MATLAB and this command is complex for me can u use more simple?

Comment: more simple than one single function? what??

Comment: i used that and i faced a blank image !!!

Comment: If your original image was uint8 then you might have to typecast back to that. I'll edit.

Comment: What is that error related to? Error using bsxfun
Mixed integer class inputs are not supported.

Comment: @MohammadFarahi you have to cast `I_colour` to a double first, see my edit. Also please read up on typecasting. This is a good starting point: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/22785-double-and-uint8

Answer (score 1):

Here's some edits to Dan's answer and additional stuffs to answer your question.

Code -

```
%// Load image
I_colour = imread('pic1.jpg');

%// Dan's method with the correct (correct if you can rely on MATLAB's paramters,
%// otherwise Dan's mentioned paramters could be correct, but I couuldn't verify)
%//  parameters** as listed also in RGB2GRAY documentation and at - 
%// http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99136
W = permute([0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140], [3,1,2]);  
I_grey = sum(bsxfun(@times, double(I_colour), W),3);

%// MATLAB's in-built function
I_grey2 = double(rgb2gray(I_colour));

%// Error checking between our and MATLAB's methods
error = rms(abs(I_grey(:)-I_grey2(:)))

figure, 
subplot(211),imshow(uint8(I_grey));
subplot(212),imshow(uint8(I_grey2));
```

Mathworks guys have beautifully answered this with simple to understand code at - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99136

Answer (score 0):

The function `rgb2gray` eliminates **hue** and **saturation** and retains the information about **luminance(brightness)**.

So, you can convert a pixel located at i and j into grayscale by using following formula.

### Formula

```
grayScaleImage(i,j) = 0.298*img(i,j,1)+0.587*img(i,j,2)+0.114*img(i,j,3)
```

img(i,j,1) is value of RED pixel.

img(i,j,2) is value of GREEN pixel.

img(i,j,3) is value of BLUE pixel.

grayScaleImage(i,j) is value of the pixel in grayscale in range[0..255]

### Psuedo Code

```
img = imread('example.jpg');
[r c colormap] = size(img);
for i=1:r
 for j=1:c
  grayScaleImg(i,j) = 0.298*img(i,j,1)+0.587*img(i,j,2)+0.114*img(i,j,3);
 end 
end
imshow(grayScaleImg);
```