# Matlab error: Undefined function 'svd' for input arguments of type 'uint8'

Tags: matlab

I imported a .jpg file into Matlab and want to find the single value decompositions of the image.

```
  x=imread('mypicture.jpg');

  [U, S, V]=svd(x);
```

However doing so I ran into the following error: Undefined function 'svd' for input arguments of type 'uint8'. How can I go about resolving this?

I also tried

```
  [U, S, V]=svd(double(x));
```

but I get the error: Error using svd Input must be 2-D.

Comment: Needs a 2D image, that is a gray or binary image. Or process for each channel separately in case you HAVE to use all three channels of a RGB image.

Comment: your `x` has a third dimension holding the RGB channels. Try converting it to grey first? `[U,S,V] = svd(rgb2gray(x))` (or if you don't have the image processing toolbox [then try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007612/convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale-in-matlab-without-rgb2gray/22007627#22007627))

Comment: @Dan: Why don't you post that as an answer, so I can vote it up? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `x` has a third dimension holding the RGB channels. Try converting it to grey first?

```
[U,S,V] = svd(rgb2gray(x))
```

or if you don't have the image processing toolbox: [Convert a color image to grayscale in MATLAB without rgb2gray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007612/convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale-in-matlab-without-rgb2gray/22007627#22007627)