# Algorithm of bitmap getbrightness() in C#

Tags: c#

I want to implement a function in java that calculate brightness of a color exactly as same as  C# getbrightness() function. So I need to know the exact algorithm that used in C#. There is some algorithms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color) but all of them have about 5% error.

Comment: Luminance != brightness

Comment: Another thing, in Image Processing the term brightness can refer to about 73 similar but different things...

Comment: Note that `Color.GetBrightness()` brings back `0.5` for `Blue` as well as `Yellow`. So it really is totally useless for anything in the real world of colors.. - It may have some reason deep inside of GDI+, although I don't what that could be..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use official source:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs#23adaaa39209cc1f

```
public float GetBrightness()
{
    float r = (float)R / 255.0f;
    float g = (float)G / 255.0f;
    float b = (float)B / 255.0f;

    float max, min;

    max = r; min = r;

    if (g > max) max = g;
    if (b > max) max = b;

    if (g < min) min = g;
    if (b < min) min = b;

    return (max + min) / 2;
}
```

Comment: Better than `ILSpy`, this way you get variable names too!