# Grayscale image and L*a*b space in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, colors, lab-color-space

I have a bunch of images, the vast majority of which are color (rgb) images. I need to apply some spatial features in the three different channels of their Lab color space. The conversion from RGB Color space to Lab color space is straightforward through `rgb2gray`. However, this naturally fails when the image is grayscale (consists of one channel only, with the numerical representation being a `double`, `uint8`, anything really).

I am familiar with the fact that the "luminance" (L) channel of the Lab color space is essentially the grayscaled original RGB image. This question, however, is of a different nature; what I'm asking is: Given an image that is already grayscale, I trivially get the L channel in Lab color space. **What should the a and b channels be**? Should they be zero? The following example, using the pre-build "peppers" image, shows the visual effect of doing so:

```
I = imread('peppers.png');
figure; imshow(I, []);
Lab = rgb2gray(I);
Lab(:, :, 2) = 0;
Lab(:, :, 3) = 0;
figure; imshow(Lab, []);
```

If you run this code, you will note that the second `imshow` outputs a reddish version of the first image, resembling an old dark room. I admit to not being knowledgeable about what the a and b color channels represent in order to understand how I should deal with them in grayscale images, and was looking for some assistance.

Comment: a and b in L*a*b colorspace define the coordinates of a matrix, the value of which defines the color of that pixel.  `imshow` assumes RGB input so when you provide non-zero values in only the one channel, `imshow` displays that as intensity only in the red channel.  It doesn't automatically know you are giving it Lab colorspace values.  If you want your image to appear grayscale with `imshow` either give it only a 2D matrix or have all three planes (`Lab(:,:,1:3)`) all equal the same 2D matrix.

Comment: Thanks. Essentially what I'm asking, however, is not this, but the following: if I have a grayscale image, what is its equivalent Lab-space representation?

Comment: You're doing it right. You want `a* = 0` and `b* = 0` for grayscale. @Staus has explained why `imshow` displays a red image. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

### An XY Type of Question.

IN CIELAB, a* and b* at 0 means no chroma: i.e. it's greyscale.

***BUT WAIT THERE'S MORE!*** If you're having problems it's because that's not the actual question you need answered:

### Incorrect Assumptions

First off, no, The L* of `L*a*b*` is NOT Luminance, and it is not the same as luminance.

**Luminance** (L or Y) is a linear measure of light.

**L*** (*Lstar) is perceptual lightness, it follows human perception (more or less, depending on a bazillion contextual things).

### rgb2grey

rgb2grey does not convert to `L*a*b*`

Also, unfortunately some of the MATLAB functions for colorspaces have errors in implementation.

If you want to convert an sRGB color/image/pixel to LAB, then you need to follow this flowchart:

**sRGB -> linear RGB -> CIEXYZ -> CIELAB**

If you only want the greyscale or lightness information, with no color you can:

**sRGB -> linear RGB -> CIE Y** (spectral weighting) **-> L*** (perceptual lightness)

I discuss this simple method of [sRGB to L* in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56678483/10315269)

And if you want to see more in depth details, [I suggest Bruce Lindbloom.](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Math.html)