# Why does 4294967295 >> 24 == -1 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am calculating luminosity in Javascript using:

```
luminosity = (5036060 * backgroundColor.red + 9886846 * backgroundColor.green + 1920103 * backgroundColor.blue) >> 24;
```

For the case where the color is white, ie all 3 RGB values are 255, I am getting a result of -1. I tested explicitly and in Javascript the value "4294967295 >> 24" is -1.

Why?

Comment: Why don't you calculate the luminosity as a floating point value [0,1]?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript does use 32-bit integers for bitwise operations. The unsigned value `+4294967295` has just the same representation as `-1` for signed 32-bit integers - a series of 32 `1`-bits. If you shift that using the [*signed* right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Right_shift) operator, it will get filled up with the sign bit, and `-1 >> x` always ends up with `-1`.

Use the [*unsigned* right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#>>>_(Zero-fill_right_shift)) operator instead:

```
4294967295 >>> 24 // 255
```

Comment: So I should just do a divide then? Or is there a more efficient way to get it?

Comment: @DavidThielen: Yes, `Math.floor(x / (1<<24))` will work, but rather use `>>>` when you want to do integer magic. For [your particular use case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/596243/1048572), I'd recommend to just use floating-point math though.

Comment: I used the >>> 24 as you put above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`>>` is defined like this:

> [**11.7.2 - The Signed Right Shift Operator ( >> )**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.2)
>
> Performs a sign-filling bitwise right shift operation on the left
>   operand by the amount specified by the right operand.
>
> The production *ShiftExpression* : *ShiftExpression* `>>` *AdditiveExpression*
>   is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *ShiftExpression*.
> 2. Let *lval* be [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)(*lref*).
> 3. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *AdditiveExpression*.
> 4. Let *rval* be [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)(*rref*).
> 5. Let *lnum* be [ToInt32](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5)(*lval*).
> 6. Let *rnum* be [ToUint32](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.6)(*rval*).
> 7. Let *shiftCount* be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of *rnum*, that is, compute *rnum* & 0x1F.
> 8. Return the result of performing a sign-extending right shift of *lnum* by *shiftCount* bits. The most significant bit is propagated. The
>      result is a signed 32-bit integer.

And ToInt32 like this:

> [**9.5 - ToInt32: (Signed 32 Bit Integer)**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5)
>
> The abstract operation ToInt32 converts its argument to one of 2<sup>32</sup>
>   integer values in the range −2<sup>31</sup> through 2<sup>31</sup>−1, inclusive. This
>   abstract operation functions as follows:
>
> 1. Let *number* be the result of calling [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) on the input argument.
> 2. If *number* is **NaN**, **+0**, **−0**, **+∞**, or **−∞**, return **+0**.
> 3. Let *posInt* be [sign](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-5.2)(*number*) * [floor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-5.2)([abs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-5.2)(*number*)).
> 4. Let *int32bit* be posInt [modulo](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-5.2) 2<sup>32</sup>; that is, a finite integer value k of Number type with positive sign and less than 2<sup>32</sup> in magnitude
>      such that the mathematical difference of *posInt* and k is
>      mathematically an integer multiple of 2<sup>32</sup>.
> 5. If *int32bit* is greater than or equal to 2<sup>31</sup>, return *int32bit* − 2<sup>32</sup>, otherwise return *int32bit*.

Therefore, `ToInt32(4294967295)` is `-1`.

And `-1 >> 24` is `-1`