# Relationship between Gamma Correction and Perceived Brightness

Tags: colors, brightness, gamma

I would be very happy to know that the **Relationship** between **Gamma Correction** and **Perceived Brightness**.

[>>> this is what makes me raise this question...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13558570/4938480)

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to understand perceived brightness, this link here might be useful: http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/04/27/Calculating-the-Perceived-Brightness-of-a-Color.aspx

Gamma correction, on the other hand, deals with changing the perceived brightness so that colors may be displayed correctly, on an output device, say a LCD screen.

http://www.cgsd.com/papers/gamma_intro.html