# Why is Java incorrectly saving the colors of pixels with a low alpha value and how to prevent it?

Tags: java, javafx, colors

Mainly using JavaFX, I'm trying to take an existing image and convert it so that it's all a single color, but with darker colors being more opaque and lighter colors more transparent.
Simply put, for each pixel, I add the R, G, B values, divide it by 3, subtract that from 255, and set that as the alpha. The R, G, B values are constant, in my example case they are 54, 57, 62.
I can't quite identify where the problem occurs, but looking at the output, the color is correct for opaque (dark) pixels, and the lower the alpha drops, the less the colors are as they're supposed to be.

```
Examples:
54, 58, 63 for Alpha = 57
52, 60, 60 for Alpha = 34
36, 73, 73 for Alpha = 7
```

```
WritableImage out = new WritableImage(width, height);
PixelWriter setPixel = out.getPixelWriter();
PixelFormat<IntBuffer> pixelFormat = PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance();
PixelReader getPixel = in.getPixelReader();

int[][] imageData = new int[height][width];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        imageData[y][x] = getPixel.getArgb(x, y);
    }
}
int[][][] inRgba = Tools.intToRgba(imageData, width, height);

System.out.println("Enter the R, G, B components of the output, in order.");
int outR = input.nextInt();
int outG = input.nextInt();
int outB = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); //To clear the newline.

int[][][] outRgba = new int[height][width][4];

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        outRgba[y][x] = new int[] {outR, outG, outB, 255 - (int) Math.round((inRgba[y][x][0] + inRgba[y][x][1] + inRgba[y][x][2]) / 3.0)};
    }

int[] outputBuffer = Tools.rgbaToInt(outRgba, width, height);
setPixel.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, pixelFormat, outputBuffer, 0, width);

File file = Files.createFile(Paths.get(path2)).toFile();
ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(out, null), "png", file);
```

```
public static int[] rgbaToInt(int[][][] image, int width, int height) {
    int[] intBuffer = new int[height * width];

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            intBuffer[y * width + x] = (image[y][x][3] << 24) | (image[y][x][0] << 16 ) | (image[y][x][1] << 8) | image[y][x][2];
        }
    }

    return intBuffer;
}
```

The (hopefully) relevant portions of my script.

Comment: You mean they don't appear as you think they should, or the raw values are wrong? If it's the first - an image example may help.

Comment: You don't describe very well what you want to achieve.  You say you want it all to be a single color, yet you donot conver the colors at all (to say grayscale for example).

Comment: Also, are you sure the output of `Tools.rgbaToInt` is correct? Maybe you should post it as well (I'm assuming this is a method you have written)

Comment: @sillyfly Both, but yes the raw values are wrong. I will post the method as well, but I doubt something went wrong there, rather when writing it to the image or saving it into a file.

Comment: @john16384 I do change the colors. Near the middle of my script, the user enters the RGB values, and those values are set to every pixel in the loop after.

Comment: Hmm... could it be only the fact that in your loop you use `height` twice instead of `height` and `width`?

Comment: @sillyfly That is most probably a bug, thank you for mentioning it, but as the images I've used it on have been coincidentally square, it is not the source of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close to what you want to achieve.  But instead of keeping the original colors, you should just set R, G and B to (255, 255, 255) plus your calculated alpha.

Comment: That is not what I wish to achieve though. In your case, if the image was displayed on a gray background, the non-transparent parts would look white instead of gray.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your output looks wierd because you're not properly taking the brightness of colors into account.   Averaging the RGB values for alpha won't give a good result.  Generally you use a formula like:

```
 0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B
```

See [Formula to determine brightness of RGB color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color)

Comment: The output doesn't look weird and in fact looks almost like it's supposed to. This is not a visual problem but rather that I set every pixel on the picture to have the same RGB values, but opening the image after it's saved, the colors are not the same.