# Histogram: RGB to Luminosity

Tags: swift, histogram, rgb, core-image, luminance

In the histogram display I am implementing, I managed to successfully display **RGB histogram**.  When compared with Photoshop's, it seems right-on!

*(All screenshots below are from same image)*

[image]

---

Now, for **Luminosity histogram**, I used the following formula:

```
Y = 0.2126 R + 0.7152 G + 0.0722 B
```

(as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/596241/637988))

However, mine seems to be off from Photoshop's **Luminosity Histogram** (also from other applications'):

[image]

In fact, my **Luminosity Histogram** (calculated from above formula), seems to be equal to Photoshop's **RGB Histogram**:

[image]

### Issue

What could be the proper formula to implement the proper **Luminosity Histogram** from RGB values?

---

P.S. : I've tried following formulas, but they don't seem to get me close to Photoshop's actual **Luminosity Histogram**:

```
Y = 0.2126 R + 0.7152 G + 0.0722 B
Y = 0.299 R + 0.587 G + 0.114 B
Y = 0.33 R + 0.5 G + 0.16 B
Y = 0.375 R + 0.5 G + 0.125 B
```

---

*(Please note: I do understand, due to color space differences, actual formulas used by different applications, etc., histograms tend to differ slightly from one application to another. I used Photoshop as a common example.  I also did compare with other image editing softwares, and the differences seemed the same.)*

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? In my opinion, one option is to convert RGB to HSL and then get L part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

Prior to applying the coefficients, you must linearize the sRGB values.

## Longer Answer

1. The appropriate term is **luminance**. Luminosity is light over time, used in astronomy for starlight intensity.
2. sRGB, and most RGB color spaces used for storing or transmitting color data are using values encoded with a gamma or transfer curve, aka a "TRC or tone response curve.

   - Therefore, there is not a linear 1:1 relationship between sRGB values and the actual light output at the display.
3. On the otherhand, luminance is a linear value of light intensity. While Luminance has a spectral weighting per human sensitivity to different wavelengths, luminance is not relative to the human perception of lightness/darkness, and the human lightness perceptuion is non-linear relative to physical light intensity.

   - An implication here is that in order for the colorimetric coefficients used for calculating linear luminance to work as intended, the non-linear sRGB values ***must be linearized first***.
4. The reasons for the use of gamma / TRC are well described in Dr. Poynton's ["Gamma FAQ"](https://poynton.ca/GammaFAQ.html).