# how to get the lightest color from a list of hex values using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of hex colors #000000 values. How can I get the lightest color from a list of hex colors using javascript?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: if the list is #000000 values, then they're all the same :p

Comment: What do you consider the lightest between #FF0000 and #00FF00 ?

Comment: @Kaiido  Well, between #FF0000 and #0000FF, the lightest must be #00FF00 :)

Comment: consider converting the colour to HSL colour space - https://gist.github.com/mjackson/5311256 - the highest `l` wins :p

Comment: `but he considers #FF0000 as brighter than #00FF00` - who does? the OP certainly has made no such declaration @Kaiido

Comment: @Kaiido - `between #FF0000 and #0000FF, the lightest must be #00FF00` is clearly tongue in cheek ...

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/596243/5053002)

Comment: there's a comment on that answer with a link to a nice fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/sbrexep0/

Answer (score 2):

According to this [**formula**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/596243/6647153), you can calculate the luminance (brightness) of an RGB color like this:

```
L = 0.2126*R + 0.7152*G + 0.0722*B;
```

you can apply this on hex which won't be hard, then get the color with the maximum brightness:

```js
function lum(hex) {
  var r = parseInt(hex.substr(1, 2), 16),
      g = parseInt(hex.substr(3, 2), 16),
      b = parseInt(hex.substr(5, 2), 16);
      
  return 0.2126*r + 0.7152*g + 0.0722*b;;
}

function lightest(colors) {
  var maxIndex = 0,
      maxLum = lum(colors[0]);
      
  for(var i = 1; i < colors.length; i++) {
    var iLum = lum(colors[i]);
    if(maxLum < iLum) {
      maxLum = iLum;
      maxIndex = i;
    }
  }
  
  return colors[maxIndex];
}

console.log(lightest(["#ff0000", "#ffcd00", "#000000"]));
```