# Swift SceneKit lighting and effecting emission texture

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm developing an app which is about the solar system.
I'm trying to turnoff the Emission Texture, where the light hits the surface of the planet. But the problem is that an emission texture by default, always shows the emission points regardless the absence or presence of the light.

My request in a nutshell: ( I wanna hide the emission points, on places where the light hits the surface ) [image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = SCNScene()

    let earth = SCNSphere(radius: 1)
    let earthNode = SCNNode()
    let earthMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    earthMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "earth.jpg")
    earthMaterial.emission.contents = UIImage(named: "earthEmission.jpg")
    earth.materials = [earthMaterial]
    earthNode.geometry = earth
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(earthNode)

    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light?.type = .omni
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 5)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

    sceneView.scene = scene


}
```

Comment: Facing the same problem right now, emission should only show on the night-side, i.e. the side lit by the SCNLight. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Does SceneKit have bitmap masking of textures?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SceneKit's [shader modifiers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable) are a perfect fit for this kind of task.

You can see footage of the final result [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLEL7kZBgZ4).

### Fragment shader modifier

[image: visual representation of _lightingContribution.diffuse and the final result of the shader modifier]

We can use `_lightingContribution.diffuse` (RGB (`vec3`) color representing lights that are applied to the diffuse) to determine areas of an object (in this case - Earth) that are illuminated and then use it to mask the emission texture in the [fragment shader modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadermodifierentrypoint/1523342-fragment).

The way you use it is really up to you. Here's the simplest solution I've come up with (using `GLSL` syntax, though it will be automatically converted to `Metal` at runtime if you are using it)

```
uniform sampler2D emissionTexture;

vec3 light = _lightingContribution.diffuse;
float lum = max(0.0, 1 - (0.2126*light.r + 0.7152*light.g + 0.0722*light.b)); // 1
vec4 emission = texture2D(emissionTexture, _surface.diffuseTexcoord) * lum; // 2, 3
_output.color += emission; // 4
```

1. calculate luminance (using formula [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/596243/6192057)) of the `_lightingContribution.diffuse` color (in case the lighting is not pure white)
2. subtract it from one to get luminance of the "dark side"
3. get emission from a custom texture using diffuse UV coordinates (granted emission and diffuse textures have the same ones) and apply luminance to it by multiplication
4. Add it to the final output color (the same way regular emission is applied)

That's it for the shader part, now let's go though the Swift side of things.

---

### Swift setup

First-off, we **are not** going to use `emission.contents` property of a material, instead we would need to create a custom `SCNMaterialProperty`

```
let emissionTexture = UIImage(named: "earthEmission.jpg")!
let emission = SCNMaterialProperty(contents: emissionTexture)
```

and set it to the material using `setValue(_:forKey:)`

```
earthMaterial.setValue(emission, forKey: "emissionTexture")
```

**Pay close attention** to the key – it should be the same as the uniform in the shader modifier. Also you don't need to persist the material property yourself, `setValue` creates a strong reference.

All that is left to do is to set the fragment shader modifier to the material:

```
let shaderModifier =
"""
uniform sampler2D emissionTexture;

vec3 light = _lightingContribution.diffuse;
float lum = max(0.0, 1 - (0.2126*light.r + 0.7152*light.g + 0.0722*light.b));
vec4 emission = texture2D(emissionTexture, _surface.diffuseTexcoord) * lum;
_output.color += emission;
"""
earthMaterial.shaderModifiers = [.fragment: shaderModifier]
```

Here's [footage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLEL7kZBgZ4) of this shader modifier in motion.

Note that a light source has to be quite bright otherwise dim lights are going to be seen around the "globe". I had to set `lightNode.light?.intensity` to at least 2000 in your setup for it to work as expected. You might want to experiment with the way luminosity is calculated and applied to emission to get better results.

---

In case you might need it, `_lightingContribution` is a structure available in the fragment shader modifier that has also has `ambient` and `specular` members (below is `Metal` syntax):

```
struct SCNShaderLightingContribution {
    float3 ambient;
    float3 diffuse;
    float3 specular;
} _lightingContribution;
```

Comment: Thank you Lësha, that worked exactly as I needed it. Also very happy I know now how to setup shader modifiers, have done that before in Unity, just not in Swift/Scenekit yet!

Answer (score 1):

I like Lësha's answer, made a small modification to the shader so that it will work with lower light levels. Added a threshold (t) below which emission values will not show, and then between the threshold and zero it interpolates values between diffuse and diffuse + emission. Changing the value of t adusts the width of the band depicting the transition between night and day. I also appended a 0.5 multiplier on the emission formula, since the emission texture I'm using looked artificially bright without it.

```
let shaderModifier =
"""
uniform sampler2D emissionTexture;

vec3 light = _lightingContribution.diffuse;
float lum = max(0.0, 1 - (0.2126*light.r + 0.7152*light.g + 0.0722*light.b));
vec4 emission = texture2D(emissionTexture, _surface.diffuseTexcoord) * lum * 0.5;
float t = 0.11; // no emission will show above this threshold
_output.color = vec4(
    light.r > t ? _output.color.r : light.r/t * _output.color.r + (1-light.r/t) * (_output.color.r + emission.r),
    light.g > t ? _output.color.g : light.g/t * _output.color.g + (1-light.g/t) * (_output.color.g + emission.g),
    light.b > t ? _output.color.b : light.b/t * _output.color.b + (1-light.b/t) * (_output.color.b + emission.b),1);
"""
```