# How can we calculate Mean Square Error(MSE) of two RGB Images

Tags: math

How the MSE between two images in RGB format be calculated, as it has 3 components R,G and B but the formula depicts the single term.

Comment: Depends on why do you need MSE. If it’s something like motion detection, just use brightness value of each pixels.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/596243/126995

Comment: You can calculate the distances between two points in a 3D space.