# Why are these particular values used to convert image to grayscale in python?

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to convert my RGB image to Grayscale. While doing it, I came across the code:

`np.dot(rgbImage[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])`

Can anyone please explain this line and values taken.?
(Please don't provide any Wikipedia link)
searching for a simple explanation.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Maybe, but colour conversions are a common thing in programming, comparable to e.g. text encoding. The way it is formulated, the question is perhaps too specific, but I think it is _good enough_.

Comment: It is based on a standard. It balances the human eye response.

Answer (score 3):

It is like converting into Grayscale using weighted or Luminosity method

Luminosity = 0.299 × R + 0.587 × G + 0.114 × B

It means 29.9% for RED, 58.7% for Green, and 11.4% Blue.

Comment: For more info, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/596243/389289)