# What's this brightness function

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, image-manipulation, brightness

The brightness of an image can be measured by the below function as this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/289340259_Generic_and_real-time_detection_of_specular_reflections_in_images) mentioned
[image]

In this paper, they didn't talk about Cr, Cg and Cb. Can anyone explain this function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably it is related to  ** colour spaces** refer [this](https://youtu.be/LFXN9PiOGtY) video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Cr: Red channel
- Cg: Green Channel
- Cb: Blue Channel

The coefficients (0.241, 0.691, 0.068) are used to calculate the [luminance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color)

For example:

If you have a color (RGB) image and you want to convert to greyscale:

- 1. You will extract each channel from the image
- 2. greyscale = (0.2126 * Cr) + (0.7152 * Cg) + (0.0722 * Cb)

The coefficients are recommended by [ITU-BT709](https://www.itu.int/rec/R-REC-BT.709) and are standards for HDTV.

So for calculating the brightness the accepted coefficients are 0.241, 0.691, and 0.068.

***UPDATE**:
Check more about new coefficients [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/596243/5941807).*

You can print the brightness values:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# img will be BGR image
img = cv2.imread("samurgut3.jpeg")
#When we square the values overflow will occur if we have uint8 type
img = np.float64(img)
# Extract each channel
Cr = img[:, :, 2]
Cg = img[:, :, 1]
Cb = img[:, :, 0]

# Get width and height
Width = img.shape[0]
Height = img.shape[1]
#I don't think so about the height and width will not be here
brightness = np.sqrt((0.241 * (Cr**2)) + (0.691 * (Cg**2)) + (0.068 * (Cb**2))) / (Width * Height)
#We convert float64 to uint8
brightness =np.uint8(np.absolute(brightness))

print(brightness)
```

Output:

```py
[[4.42336257e-05 4.09825832e-05 4.09825832e-05 ... 3.44907525e-05
  4.13226678e-05 4.13226678e-05]
 [4.09825832e-05 4.09825832e-05 4.09825832e-05 ... 3.44907525e-05
  4.13226678e-05 4.13226678e-05]
```

Answer (score 1):

the *squaring* is probably an attempt to convert from *gamma-mapped* values to *linear values*.

A somewhat better exponent would be something around `1/0.45` (~2.22) or 2.2 or 2.4.

An even better operation would be to find out the actual gamma curve and apply that. sRGB is defined piecewise and does not match exactly to a simple exponentiation.