# Do all object variables need to be defined in the constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I was wondering if all `self.` has to be defined in `__init__`, for example, i have this code right here:

```
class Colour:

    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        self._red = r
        self._green = g
        self._blue = b
        self._rgb = (self._red, self._green, self._blue)


    

    def luminosity(self):
        self._luminosity = 0.5 * ((max(self._red, self._green, self._blue))/255)+((min(self._red, self._green, self._blue))/255)
        return self._luminosity
```

Am i right to define `self.luminosity` in the function `def luminosity(self)` or should i define it in `__init__`?

Comment: According to PEP8 all instance attributes should be defined in `__init__`, so you can do  `self._luminosity = self.luminosity()`

Comment: Nothing to stop you defining them whenever you want, assuming you defend or control so you don’t get exceptions - but your class will likely be easier to understand if you initialise instance variables in `__init__()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to define it, because it's only set and then returned when you could directly return the calculated value from your method!

Additionally, you can simplify the calculation a little, though I am not sure it is really luminosity, as there are [a variety of interpretations different to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/596216/4541045)

```py
    def luminosity(self):
        return 0.5 * (
            max(self._red, self._green, self._blue) + \
            min(self._red, self._green, self._blue)
        ) / 255
```

If *instead*, you were caching the value (which may make sense if you do a more complex calculation or call the `luminosity` method many times), it would make sense to set it in `__init__()` and check before calculating (effectively caching the last call)

As **@laol** suggests, you can also use `@property` to simplify some of the its use

And finally, you can take advantage of your combined RGB for the calculation

```py
class Colour():

    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        self._red = r
        self._green = g
        self._blue = b
        self._luminosity = None

    @property
    def rgb(self):
        return (self._red, self._green, self._blue)

    @property
    def luminosity(self):
        if self._luminosity is None:
            self._luminosity = 0.5 * (max(self.rgb) + min(self.rgb)) / 255
        return self._luminosity
```

```py
c = Colour(128,100,100)
print(c.luminosity)

0.44705882352941173
```

Extending this even further, setting new values for the color components can set the cached value back to `None`, triggering re-calculation on the *next* call (rather than immediately, saving some calculation if many changes are made before the value is wanted), but this is left as an exercise to the reader

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to define it as a property:

```
 @property
def luminosity(self):
    return 0.5 * ((max(self._red, self._green, self._blue))/255)+((min(self._red, self._green, self._blue))/255)
```

By this you can directly return it from any Colour c by

```
c.luminosity
```

Answer (score 2):

No, instance variables do not need to be defined in `__init__`. Instance variables are completely dynamic and can be added any time either in a method or outside of the object (see note). However, if you don't define them, you have created an object access protocol that needs to be managed. Suppose another method is added:

```
def half_luminosity(self):
    return self._luminosity/2
```

It is an error to call it before `luminosity`. This code will raise `AttributeError` if its called at the wrong time. You could assign `self._luminosity = None` in `__init__` and check it

```
def half_luminosity(self):
    if self._luminosity is None:
        raise ValueError("Attempt to use luminosity before set")
```

but that's not much different than

```
def half_luminosity(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_luminosity'):
        raise ValueError("Attempt to use luminosity before set")
```

If you have a class that is setup in more than one step, either way will do. PEP8 favors the first because its easier for a futurer reader to see what's going on.

NOTE: Classes  that use `__slots__` or one of the `getattr` methods can change the rules as can C extensions.