# convert RGB to black and white

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

The code snippet in Python should convert the rgb image to black and white, but only a black image output. I do not know where the problem is (input and output image should be bmp)

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

raw_img = Image.open(r"image adress")
img = raw_img.load()
x,y = raw_img.size
threshold = 300
bw_img = [[0]*y]*x # blank image

for i in range(x):
  for j in range(y):
    if img[i,j] < threshold:
      bw_img[i][j] = 0
    else:
      bw_img[i][j] = 1


Image.fromarray(np.asarray(bw_img),mode="P").save("your_nwe_image.bmp")
```

Comment: Running `for` loops over any image bigger than about 20 pixels on either side is almost always hopelessly inefficient and sub-optimal. You really should use Numpy or something vectorised or implemented in C like PIL's `point` process.

Comment: Why did you expect that there are values above 300 in your image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to replace

```
threshold = 300
```

with

```
threshold = 128
```

because `Image.open` always returns an 8-bit image where 255 is the maximum value.

Here is how I would go about doing this *(without using the OpenCV module)*:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def not_black(color):
    return (color * [0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722]).sum(-1) < 128

raw_img = Image.open(r"image adress")
img = np.array(raw_img)

whites = not_black(img)
img[whites] = 255
img[~whites] = 0

Image.fromarray(img).save("your_nwe_image.bmp")
```

However, *with* OpenCV, it simplifies to just:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(r"biss3.png", 0)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imwrite("your_nwe_image.bmp", thresh)
```

Comment: It has an error code:    return ((color * [0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722]).sum(-1) < 128)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (479,600) (3,)

Comment: @AmirHussain Right under `img = np.array(raw_img)` add `img = np.dstack((img, img, img))`.

Comment: The output image is just a white image and does not work

Comment: My problem is solved, thank you. What exactly do these two lines do? def not_black(color):
    return ((color * [0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722]).sum(-1) < 128)                                  . and                                                                                                                    img = np.dstack((img, img, img))

Comment: Where exactly do those 0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722 numbers come from?

Comment: @AmirHussain Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/596243/13552470