# How can I get the luminance intensity of colors on the screen in C#?

Tags: c#, colors, screen, desktop-application, pixel

I'm going to make a desktop application with C#, but I'm having trouble with something. I need to achieve the brightness of the colors on the screen. In other words, how light or how dark the colors on the screen are right now. How can I achieve this or is there a library I can use?

When I did a little research, I saw that I could find the colors on the screen as pixels, but this is not my goal. Thank you from now.

Comment: I'm not sure how "I saw that I could find the colors on the screen as pixels" _isn't_ what you're after. You can determine the "brightness" of a pixel from its RGB values. You can't, for example, see how many photons the monitor is capable of outputting.

Comment: @gunr2171 Let me describe my sentence again as follows. I came across a sample project that searches for a specific color code on the screen and returns its pixel. That's what I meant there.
I want to reach the brightness values ​​of the colors of the pixels on the screen, or as you say, I need to reach the colors of all the pixels on the screen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-perceived-brightness-of-rgb-color

Comment: @gunr2171 Thank you. I guess I should reach the color values ​​of the pixels on the screen and get an average brightness value. But how can I get the color values ​​of all pixels on the screen?

Comment: @gunr2171 Maybe I can try using that I hope it works. Thanks a lot for your help.