# Calculating a total luminance value of an image in r

Tags: r

How can I go about retrieving a total luminance value of a .png image, better yet - a way to do this for every image contained within a folder?

I've come across two resources, however, for one (https://rdrr.io/github/mokazuma/imhistR/man/lrgbhist.html#heading-1) I'm struggling to even download the package and the other ([Formula to determine perceived brightness of RGB color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-perceived-brightness-of-rgb-color)) seems to lack consensus on how luminance should be calculated?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "total"?

Comment: average across all RBG channels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can install the `imhistR` package.

1. Install the `remotes` package.

```r
install.packages('remotes')
```

2. Install the `datautils` package:

```r
remotes::install_github("holgerbrandl/datautils", dependencies=TRUE)
```

3. Install the (removed from CRAN) `patchPlot` package:

```r
remotes::install_url('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/patchPlot/patchPlot_0.1.5.tar.gz', dependencies = TRUE)
```

4. Install the (removed from CRAN) `imhistR` package:

```r
remotes::install_github("mokazuma/imhistR", dependencies=TRUE)
```

5. Test the `imhistR` package:

```
require("imhistR")
lrgbhist(input, mode = "file", output = input, hist = TRUE,
  resize = FALSE, endoff = FALSE, textsize = 16)
```

On my system, this yields:

```r
trying URL 'https://www.r-project.org/Rlogo.png'
Content type 'image/png' length 32553 bytes (31 KB)
downloaded 31 KB

          Mean_Luminance SD_Luminance Skew_Luminance
Rlogo.png      0.5307022    0.1816393      0.1654525
          Kurt_Luminance Mean_Red    SD_Red   Skew_Red
Rlogo.png      -1.697913  0.42456 0.2849509 0.01362389
           Kurt_Red Mean_Green  SD_Green Skew_Green
Rlogo.png -1.875264   0.552168 0.1613232  0.2315529
          Kurt_Green Mean_Blue    SD_Blue Skew_Blue
Rlogo.png  -1.657691 0.7183205 0.05884395 -1.220589
          Kurt_Blue
Rlogo.png  2.128444
Warning messages:
1: The dot-dot notation (`..x..`) was deprecated in ggplot2
3.4.0.
ℹ Please use `after_stat(x)` instead.
ℹ The deprecated feature was likely used in the imhistR
  package.
  Please report the issue at
  <https://github.com/mokazuma/imhistR/issues>.
This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where
this warning was generated. 
2: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_bar()`). 
3: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_bar()`). 
4: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_bar()`). 
5: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_bar()`).
```

and the plot:

[image: Output from imhistR::lrgbhist()]

As you can see, the package needs some TLC, but it seems to work for now.

*Edit:*

Looking at the package code (https://github.com/mokazuma/imhistR/blob/13319682f0ca0750f9c7e36b5c98c4a68b2e632b/R/lrgbhist.R#L122),
the important bits seem to be these:

```
fn = "FILE_NAME_HERE.png"
img <- readbitmap::read.bitmap(fn)
red <- img[,,1]; green <- img[,,2]; blue  <- img[,,3]
luminance <- .298912 * red + .586611 * green + .114478 * blue
mean(luminance)
```

If you install the `readbitmap` package and if you're happy with the default settings in the `imhistR::lrgbhist()` function, this code will give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the installation help, it seems to of worked. I tried the following: lrgbhist(input = "C:\\Users\\phoen\\OneDrive\\PhD\\MAGMOT\\Split_stimuli\\01_H35_combined_small\\image_000001.png", mode = "file", output = input, hist = TRUE,
         resize = FALSE, endoff = FALSE, textsize = 16) but I get this error: !! Error has occurred. Please change some parameters
object 'input' not found. Any ideas on how to rectify this?

Comment: I noticed that in my code above, I didn't define "input" (I left it to you). Can you try `input="C:\\Users\\phoen\\OneDrive\\PhD\\MAGMOT\\Split_stimuli\\01_H35_combined_small\\image_000001.png"` before running my code above?

Comment: See my edit in the answer at the bottom. I took the important code out of the package, so you don't actually need the package itself. That might make your life easier.

Comment: Hi Richard, sorry for another comment. Both your suggestions worked and I ended up opting for the first strategy as I wanted to assign the function to an entire folder not just a file. I got it to work by assigning my file path to the object 'input' but after 10 folders it no longer works. I get the following error: !! Error has occurred. Please change some parameters
invalid regular expression 'C:\Users\phoen\OneDrive - University of Reading\PhD\MAGMOT\Split_stimuli\36_Trick7_short_combined_small/', reason 'Invalid back reference' .

Comment: An example of my code that errored: input <- "C:\\Users\\phoen\\OneDrive - University of Reading\\PhD\\MAGMOT\\Split_stimuli\\10_S27_combined_small"
Lum10 <- lrgbhist(input, mode = "folder", output = input, hist = FALSE,
                 resize = FALSE, endoff = FALSE, textsize = 16)

Comment: And here's an example of one that did work: input <- "C:\\Users\\phoen\\OneDrive - University of Reading\\PhD\\MAGMOT\\Split_stimuli\\08_S12_combined_small"
Lum8 <- lrgbhist(input, mode = "folder", output = input, hist = FALSE,
                 resize = FALSE, endoff = FALSE, textsize = 16)

Comment: To work out why that's not working would require knowledge of your file system and the imhistr package, which I don't have. But if you make a simple function out of the second approach, say, getHist = function(fn){ 
img <- readbitmap::read.bitmap(fn);
red <- img[,,1]; green <- img[,,2]; blue  <- img[,,3];
luminance <- .298912 * red + .586611 * green + .114478 * blue;
return(mean(luminance));
}
...then you can do a whole folder with something like dir(FOLDERNAME) |> sapply(getHist). If you need help with this you can open a new question.