# Seeking Insights for underlying logic of Firefox's scrollbar-color CSS Property with value auto

Tags: html, css, firefox, colors, scrollbar

I am currently working with the scrollbar-color CSS property in Firefox and have encountered an interesting behavior that I'm struggling to explain. Here is a CodePen snippet to demonstrate the behavior: https://codepen.io/Thomaz-Pom/pen/oNVBvjO.

In this snippet, you can drag around and observe how the scrollbar color updates based on the scrollbar-color: auto CSS instruction. Notably, there is a noticeable switch of the scrollbar corlor which can be a full white color or a color that follows the website background.

Notably, an instance of the color `#c4a400` causes the scrollbar to turn white, while another occasion with the color `#c40089` results in the scrollbar color following the background.

I have been unable to identify a clear correlation between this color switch and the following factors:

- Color Characteristics: I observed no consistent pattern with lightness, hue, or saturation values alone.
- RGBA Color Channels: Summing or changing individual values of the RGBA color channels does not reveal a clear relationship.
- Perceived Lightness: I have explored the concept of perceived
  brightness, as discussed in this Stack Overflow post: [Formula to
  determine perceived brightness of RGB color.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-perceived-brightness-of-rgb-color)

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on understanding this underlying logic. Thank you!