# Automatically choose a good border color based on background color

Tags: php, user-interface, colors, color-picker

I'm looking for any resources on choosing "good" colors based on one specified color. Specifically if I gave an input of say... #6e93a8, a nice corporate blue, it could spit out a darker blue for a border color and perhaps a white or black for text based on how dark the given color is. Keep in mind I can input any hex value.

I have a feel this is just messing around with adding and subtracting hex values, but I'm hoping someone has done this before and has found some good resources or an algorithm.

Thanks!
Matt Mueller

Answer (score 2):

If you already know what you want to do to the colors and you just need an algorithm for transforming the colors then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359612/how-to-change-rgb-color-to-hsv) answer which contains the algorithm for converting between RGB and HSV (and back). From then on you can alter the HSV values (to make the colors ligher, darker etc) or apply rules if the color is dark or light.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I don't really see an algorithm though.. I see an answer that converts it to HSL and one that shows how HSL is different than HSV. Oh and the last one converts RGB to HSV.

Comment: I guess my point was that the manipulations you already describe (making colors darker) are easy to do when you have the color in HSV. Also perhaps this tutorial about color theory could be helpful with picking matching colors - http://www.tigercolor.com/color-lab/color-theory/color-theory-intro.htm.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This doesn't quite answer my question but it started me down the right path. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an algorithm or just a tool? [Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/) is a web-based tool for designing color schemes that I think would serve your purposes