# Color alpha-channel in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors, alpha

How do I color a cell in a datagridview with the alpha-channel? 
RGB works ok, but when specifying the alpha I get distorted numbers instead. I make this color change in the cellPainting event.

[image]

```
 e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(120, 255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: What would you expect? There is no background behind the cell, so I do not see a reason for an alpha channel.

Comment: If I knew what you know I wouldn't ask the question. So instead please explain. Why it's no background? And how do I then solve it?

Comment: Alpha = "let the background pixels shine through". Since all is white in the background it seems that you simple want to make the color lighter. This can be done solely with RGB.

Comment: It sounds like you want to reduce the lightness of the color; in other words, input the color in HSL rather than RGB.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359612/how-to-change-rgb-color-to-hsv/637025#637025)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's working.  Your screen shot shows the cell in the 3rd row getting different values and getting repainted without the BackColor erasing what was there before.  It's several digits drawn on top of each other, looks like a 4, 5 and 6.  You get more interesting effects by making the DGV smaller so a horizontal scrollbar appears.  Dragging it produces a 'smear' of digits.

This just doesn't work very well, not sure why you want to do this.  You want a good opaque background to draw new values on.  That requires an alpha of 255.

Comment: I want to have a color with alpha (over white) adjusted based on the cell value. But if I can't use the alpha channel I guess I must look into RGB calculation.