# How to change the colors of a PNG image easily?

Tags: colors, png

I have PNG images that represent playing-cards.
They are the standard colours with Clubs and Spades being blank and Diamonds and Hearts being red.

I want to create a 4-colour deck by converting the the Clubs to green and the Diamonds to blue.

I don't want to re-draw them but just changing them by hand seems a lot of work since the colours are not all "pure" but graded near the edges.

How do I do it?

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically? If so, what language? If not, what software do you have installed? (Photoshop, Paintshop Pro, GIMP, etc)

Comment: xv's colmap window does this as well (you can use `convert`'s `-fill` and `-opaque` functions to do it command line but it's insanely slow

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Photoshop - right click layer -> blending options -> color overlay
change color and save

Comment: Photoshop is too expensive and swallows my computer whole.

Answer (score 7):

This should be fairly straightforward in the gimp http://gimp.org/

First make sure your image is RGB (not indexed color) then use the "color to alpha" feature to turn the clubs/diamonds clear, then fill or set the background or whatever to get the color you want.

Comment: Downloaded the latest version of gimp but it fails to launch. Installs ok but then refuses to open.

Comment: If you're on Mac, you'll need X11, as described in the Requirements section of the download page: http://www.gimp.org/macintosh/

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to be programming an application to do all of this, the process will be something like this:

1. [Convert image from RGB to HSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359612/how-to-change-rgb-color-to-hsv)
2. adjust H value
3. Convert image back to RGB
4. Save image

Comment: Note that the accepted answer to that question is, of course, wrong.

Comment: Yes, the commenters make that clear.  But the one with the most votes is correct, and should be upvoted if you visited the link

Answer (score 3):

Use Photoshop, Paint.NET or similar software and adjust Hue.

Comment: http://www.getpaint.net/

Comment: Good idea - but with Paint.NET you are guessing when trying to do it. The way preffered is something where you could pass RGB or Hex Value and it turns it to this color - and HUE at least with Paint.NET just does not cut it since you have to guess with the scroller. Better than nothing though

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys it can be done easy in **photoshop**.

Open png photo and then check **image -> mode** value(i had indexed color). Go **image -> mode** and check **rgb** color. Now change your color EASY.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me and Photoshop is out of your price range or just overkill for what you need. [Acorn 5](http://www.flyingmeat.com/acorn/) is a much cheaper version of Photoshop with a lot of the same features. One of those features being a color change option. You can import all of the basic image formats including SVG and PNG. The color editing software works great and allows for basic color selection, RBG selection, hex code, or even a color grabber if you do not know the color. These color features, plus a whole lot image editing features, is definitely worth the $30. The only downside is that is currently only available on Mac.