# Easy way to change icons color in sprites

Tags: graphics, icons, css-sprites, paint.net

I have a set of blue icons in sprite png, is there an easy way to change the color of each icon using a tool like Paint.net 
What I've tried so far is changing pixels color one by one, but it's really troublesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've juste found an answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6059779/288387

> Use Photoshop, Paint.NET or similar software and **adjust Hue**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Photoshop to swap certain colors with colors of your choice. This way, you have more control, as you can replace each shade separately.