# Calculating a logarithmic percentage

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, math, logarithm

I have an application monitoring a number of data points and I'm performing colouring based on the linear percentage [fading between green, yellow and red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394304/algorithm-how-do-i-fade-from-red-to-green-via-yellow-using-rgb-values). This however doesn't accurately visualise the problem as the higher the number the exponentially worse it is. The range is 0 -> 30000, how can I generate what I think would be termed a logarithmic percentage value rather than a linear one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a function of the following form.

f(x) = s b<sup>x / 30000</sup> + t

We know that 0 should map to 0% and 30000 should map to 100%.

f(0) = 0
f(30000) = 100

These imply the following system of equations.

s + t = 0
s b + t = 100

The solution (with respect to b) is the following.

s = 100 / (b - 1)
t = -100 / (b - 1)

Pick a particular b > 1 value (say b = 10).  Then you get the following solution.

s = 100 / 9
t = -100 / 9

That is, the function f(x) is the following.

f(x) = (100 10<sup>x / 30000</sup> - 100) / 9

You can see a plot of this function here: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29+%3D+%28100*10%5E%28x+%2F+30000%29+-+100%29+%2F+9%2C+x+in+%5B0%2C+30000%5D)

In C# this will look like the following.

```
double x = ...;

double b = 10.0;
double s = 100.0 / (b - 1);
double t = -100.0 / (b - 1);

double f = s * Math.Pow(b, x / 30000.0) + t;
```

Comment: Surely this graph is exponential instead of logarithmic. i.e. it grows slowly and then explodes. As opposed to exploding and then growing slowly to its peak.

Comment: @IanWarburton I'm missing the point? Where in the answer do I say it's logarithmic? It's clearly exponential. :)

Comment: @IanWarburton Oh - now I see.  Why does the code use `Math.Log` instead of `Math.Pow`?  The definition of `f` at the start of the answer uses exponentation.  Good catch.

Answer (score 10):

I assume by "logarithmic percentage" you want to map your data to the range [0, 100] on a logarithmic basis.  You can try something like this:

```
double Scale(int val)
{
    if (val <= 1)
        return 0; // log is undefined for 0, log(1) = 0
    return 100 * Math.Log(val) / Math.Log(30000);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want to plot exponentially growing values.

Answer (score 2):

Improving on bmm6o's answer:

```
public static double Scale(long value, long maxInputValue, long maxOutputValue)
{
    if (value <= 1)
        return 0; // log is undefined for 0, log(1) = 0
    return maxOutputValue * Math.Log(value) / Math.Log(maxInputValue);
}
```

if you're looking for something between linear and logarithmic, the following might help:

```
public static double Scale(long value, long maxInputValue, long maxOutputValue, double scaleFactor)
{
    if (value <= 1)
        return 0; // log is undefined for 0, log(1) = 0
    return maxOutputValue * Math.Pow(Math.Log(value), scaleFactor) / Math.Pow(Math.Log(maxInputValue), scaleFactor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Math.Log(double)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x80ywz41%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or [`Math.Log(double, double)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd50b6h5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want to play around with the base) to get the logarithm of your value, which you can than map to a color value.