# Trying to convert Integer range to RGB color

Tags: java, colors

I know you guys are all very busy, so I'm gonna keep it short and to the point.

I'm currently developing a little game for fun. There's enemys in the game. For simplicity, think about them as colored squares. I want to minimize any HUD, so I decided to display the hit points of the creatures smoothly via their color 
(green for healthy, yellow for damaged, red for nearly dead).

See image :
[image]

I however really struggle to come up with a decently efficient method that converts an (int) hp-value to an RGB-color. Mapping to a single int from 0-255 would not be a problem at all - here's an example function that does exactly that:

```
public int mapHpToGreyscale(int input) {

    //input = current hp
    double minHealth = 0;
    double maxHealth = hpmax;
    double minColValue = 0;
    double maxColValue = 255;

    int output = (int) ((input - minHealth) / (maxHealth - minHealth) * (maxColValue - minColValue) + minColValue);

    return output;
}
```

Is there a quick and easy way to achieve what I want to do? I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: Not sure what is the problem here. Could you provide a [mcve], especially the expected result, with some input/output example ?

Comment: OP searches for a method to transform a value from a certain range, e.g. [0, 100] (health points) to colors green to yellow to red. OP already knows how to transform it to a grey-scale value meaning black for healthy to white for dead (or vice versa). However grey-scale is not green to yellow to red.

Comment: Its C# but the algorithm stays the same: [Algorithm: How do I fade from Red to Green via Yellow using RGB values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394304/algorithm-how-do-i-fade-from-red-to-green-via-yellow-using-rgb-values)

Comment: Also a nice approach using the **HSL** representation of a color (JavaScript): [Calculate color values from green to red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525215/calculate-color-values-from-green-to-red)

Comment: If you need the numbers in your image, then interpolate red & green as you do with grayscale. The only difference is that you need to interpolate to 511 instead of 255, and clamp larger than 255 to 255.

Comment: Works, but if you smoothly graduate from green to red by interpolating both values, then you don't receive **yellow** in the middle but **brown**: [see this image](https://i.imgur.com/IkoD2ld.jpg)

Comment: @Zabuza: I'm not sure whose comment are you responding. With my recommendation, you'll get yellow in the middle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Explanation

First off, my answer is an adapted version of this: [Calculate color values from green to red](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17527156/2411243). I decided to create a **Java** version of that **JavaScript** solution. Code which you can directly plug-in into your code without transferring everything yourself.

The idea is to use the **HSL** ([hue, saturation, lightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)) color space instead of **RGB** (red, green, blue). There red is represented by the hue value `0°` and green by `120°` with yellow in between at `60°` with *smooth transitions* in terms of hue:

[image: Hue color circle] [image: HSL color space]

We will fix a saturation of `100%` and a lightness of `50%` but you can play with these values if you like.

---

### Usage

Here is how you would use it in your code:

```
// A value between 1.0 (green) to 0.0 (red)
double percentage = ...
// Get the color (120° is green, 0° is red)
Color color = transitionOfHueRange(percentage, 120, 0);
```

And that would be the resulting range:

[image: Hue range example]

---

### Other methods

Here is the `transitionOfHueRange` method. It accepts a `percentage` value between `0.0` and `1.0` and a `hue` range between `0` and `360`:

```
public static Color transitionOfHueRange(double percentage, int startHue, int endHue) {
    // From 'startHue' 'percentage'-many to 'endHue'
    // Finally map from [0°, 360°] -> [0, 1.0] by dividing
    double hue = ((percentage * (endHue - startHue)) + startHue) / 360;

    double saturation = 1.0;
    double lightness = 0.5;

    // Get the color
    return hslColorToRgb(hue, saturation, lightness);
}
```

Here is the `hslColorToRgb` function. It accepts **HSL** values from `0.0` to `1.0`:

```
public static Color hslColorToRgb(double hue, double saturation, double lightness) {
    if (saturation == 0.0) {
        // The color is achromatic (has no color)
        // Thus use its lightness for a grey-scale color
        int grey = percToColor(lightness);
        return new Color(grey, grey, grey);
    }

    double q;
    if (lightness < 0.5) {
        q = lightness * (1 + saturation);
    } else {
        q = lightness + saturation - lightness * saturation;
    }
    double p = 2 * lightness - q;

    double oneThird = 1.0 / 3;
    double red = percToColor(hueToRgb(p, q, hue + oneThird));
    double green = percToColor(hueToRgb(p, q, hue));
    double blue = percToColor(hueToRgb(p, q, hue - oneThird));

    return new Color(red, green, blue);
}
```

The `hueToRgb` method:

```
public static double hueToRgb(double p, double q, double t) {
    if (t < 0) {
        t += 1;
    }
    if (t > 1) {
        t -= 1;
    }

    if (t < 1.0 / 6) {
        return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
    }
    if (t < 1.0 / 2) {
        return q;
    }
    if (t < 2.0 / 3) {
        return p + (q - p) * (2.0 / 3 - t) * 6;
    }
    return p;
}
```

And finally the small utility method `percToColor`:

```
public static int percToColor(double percentage) {
    return Math.round(percentage * 255);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This answer is based on the algorithm of one of the answers from [Algorithm: How do I fade from Red to Green via Yellow using RGB values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394304/algorithm-how-do-i-fade-from-red-to-green-via-yellow-using-rgb-values) that someone mentioned in a comment.

Note that `minHealth` and `minColValue` are  not used in this example, but it shouldn't be too hard to implement.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class HealthColors {

    static double minHealth = 0;// unused here
    static double maxHealth = 100;
    static double minColValue = 0;// unused here
    static double maxColValue = 255;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel content = new JPanel();

        content.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10, 2, 2));

        for (int i = 0; i < maxHealth; i++) {

            int value = (int) (Math.random() * maxHealth + 1);

            JLabel label = new JLabel("" + value, SwingConstants.CENTER);
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setBackground(mapHpToColor(value));

            content.add(label);

        }

        frame.setContentPane(content);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static Color mapHpToColor(final int input) {

        //input = current hp

        double redValue = (input > maxHealth / 2 ? 1 - 2 * (input - maxHealth / 2) / maxHealth : 1.0) * maxColValue;
        double greenValue = (input > maxHealth / 2 ? 1.0 : 2 * input / maxHealth) * maxColValue;
        double blueValue = 0;

        Color hpColor = new Color((int) redValue, (int) greenValue, (int) blueValue);

        return hpColor;
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Color {
    public int r;
    public int g;
    public int b;
    public Color() {
        r = 0;
        g = 0;
        b = 0;
    }
};

public static Color hpToColor(float hp, float maxhp) {
    Color color = new Color();
    float alpha = hp / maxhp;

    if (alpha <= 0.5) {
        color.r = 255;
        color.g = Math.round((alpha * 2) * 255);
        color.b = 0;
    } else {
        color.r = Math.round(((1 - alpha) * 2) * 255);
        color.g = 255;
        color.b = 0;
    }

    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a quick and easy way to achieve what I want to do?

Yes, there is, you could even reuse your own code, just those constants should be arguments instead:

```
public int mapHpToComponent(int input,
    double minHealth, double maxHealth,
    double minComponentValue, double maxComponentValue) {

    int output = (int) ((input - minHealth) / (maxHealth - minHealth) *
        (maxComponentValue - minComponentValue) + minComponentValue);

    return output;
}
```

Then apply it for your palette-segments. There are two of them, one running from HP=0...50, and having G=0...255, then the second segment is HP=50...100 and R=255...0:

```
public int mapHpToColor(int input){
    if(input<50){ // first segment
        int R=255;
        int G=mapHpToComponent(input,0,50,0,255);
        int B=0;
        return (R<<16)+(G<<8)+B;
    } else {
        int R=mapHpToComponent(input,50,100,255,0);
        int G=255;
        int B=0;
        return (R<<16)+(G<<8)+B;
    }
}
```

(Yes, min/maxComponentValue could rather be start/end, because that is what they really are.)