# Segmenting Part of the image using threshold

Tags: c#, image-processing, background-color, image-segmentation, threshold

Im trying to isolate and segment the yellow car body to change the color of it. in order to do that i need to separately identify the body from the image. And continue oration with the remaining white pixels. And im using C#, here the plan

```
Color d;
Color newColor = Color.YellowGreen;    
for(inti =0;i<carimage.Width;i++){
    for(intj =0;j<carimage.Height;j++){
        d = carimage.GetPixel(i, j);
            if(d.R == 255 && d.G==255 && d.B == 255)
                image.SetPixel(i, j, newColor );
    }
}
```

simple thresholding will trow the second image where car body is not separated correctly. i tried Aforge.net Fill holes image filter but no significant change has been done to the threshold image. I tried to use color filter but it i did not return a correct output due to color vary of the body. can anyone suggest and solution for this?

### Original Image

[image: original image]

### Threshold Image

[image: threshold image]

Comment: Please post the actual code. This code is obviously not the code you actually have in your program, since you have contracted `int i` into `inti`, which won't compile. Also, the code posted would, if corrected, replace the color white with the color green. The images suggests you're doing something else. Please post a coherent question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of thresholding, you might want to look into clustering.

As a quick&dirty test, I've increased the image brightness in HSB space (using Mathematica):

> brightnessAdjusted = Image[
>     Map[#^{1, 1, 0.2} &, ImageData[ColorConvert[img, "HSB"]], {2}], 
>     ColorSpace -> "HSB"]

[image]

Then I've used simple K-Nearest clustering:

> (clusters = ClusteringComponents[ColorConvert[brightnessAdjusted, "RGB"], 3, 
>       Method -> "KMeans"]) // Colorize

[image]

to find clusters of similar colors in the image (there are many more, probably more suitable clustering algorithms, so you should experiment a little). Then I can just adjust the color in one of the clusters:

> Image[MapThread[If[#1 == 2, #2[[{1, 3, 2}]], #2] &, {clusters, ImageData[brightnessAdjusted]}, 2]]

[image]

If you want to use thresholding, you should probably use a [CIE color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space), since euclidian distances in that color space are closer to human perception.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar project few years ago. I can't remember the exact details, but the idea was to shift a (not too small) sliding window over the image, and calculate the average intensity (maybe for R, G and B separately) inside the window at each position. I filled a "threshold image" with these averages, and subtracted it from the original image. There was a scaling factor somewhere, and other tuning stuff, but the point is, such an approach was way better than using a constant threshold.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a set of thresholds, you might be better of selecting yellow hues in the Hue Saturation Value [colorspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). See the related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359612/how-to-change-rgb-color-to-hsv).

Answer (score 0):

```
    I=imread('test.jpg'); 
    I=im2double(rgb2gray(I)); 
    BW=im2bw(I,0.64);imshow(BW)
```

Gives me :

[image]

I got the 0.64 threshold by looking at the image's histogram. I suggest you use MATLAB to do image processing as it is much easier. Hope that helps you in colouring the image.