# How to find out light, medium and dark color?

Tags: colors, formula

I have a color in hex format ex (c3d8f7 (light blue), 303f5a (dark blue)). How to find out if that color is light or dark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very rough algorithm: Convert the color to [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and check e.g. if `V` is above (light) 75% or below (dark) 25%.

Comment: Are you know a function in javascript to convert hex to hsv?

Comment: This link should help: http://matthaynes.net/blog/2008/08/07/javascript-colour-functions/

Comment: @sam360 See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359612/how-to-change-rgb-color-to-hsv (and maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c)