# How to replace a color in an image?

Tags: vb.net

I'm in search of a simple algorithm to replace a color in an image with a different one like in this one->
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Colorswaphelicon.png

I'm using VB.NET. Can a "flood fill" algorithm be applied for this purpose?
Please provide a link if possible.

Greetings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to replace a color of a connected area then flood fill may work for you. For changing the color in the whole image check [How to: Use a Color Remap Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b4dc1kz.aspx) and [Recoloring Images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7xw19wh.aspx) topic.

**Edit:**

To replace all intensities of a color shade, you can check and replace the color hue (e.g. see [How To Converting Colors Between RGB and HLS (HBS)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/29240)). Specifically, colors with hue and saturation within a certain range of a source color can be changed to colors with  original intensity and hue and saturation of the target color.

Also, you may find helpful [How to change RGB color to HSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359612/how-to-change-rgb-color-to-hsv/1626175#1626175) and [HSL in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942/hsl-in-net).

Comment: Thank you very much! I want to replace a whole color gradient in an image (like changing the color of the T-Shirt of a man). How can I implement flood fill for that purpose. My implementation replaces only one color (a particular RGB value) and not the whole color gradient. Thanks again!