# C# Colour Cycling MandleBrot Fractal

Tags: c#, winforms, colors

I am designing a Mandlebrot Fractal in C# which is working fine... Question is I want to cycle through all the rgb colours in effect what I think is called colour cycling... I know that I would need to convert the bitmap to a pallet and hence run through  each pixel???? How would I achieve this?? Working on this for hours now and really unsure.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) instead of RGB would probably make cycling the colors a lot easier, since you just increment (and modulo) a single value instead of trying to manage 3 of them.

Comment: I have used this for my own Mandelbrot implementation and this works great.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with @Pyritie, use HSV rather than RGB.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359612/how-to-change-rgb-color-to-hsv) for examples.

Then try this code to set palette colours of a bitmap:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, width, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

ColorPalette palette = bitmap.Palette;
palette.Entries[0] = Color.Black;
for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
{
    // set to whatever colour here...
    palette.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb((i * 7) % 256, (i * 7) % 256, 255);
}
bitmap.Palette = palette;
```

Original credit belongs to Jon Skeet, from a TPL demo of his, I think.

Comment: The "bitmap.Palette =" is critical. You seemingly can't make changes to the palette and get them to stick without that set operation. Not intuitive on MSFT's part, so thanks for the code sample.