# Implementation of SVM image annotation for color cast removal

Tags: c#, image, algorithm, image-processing

I'm implementing an [automatic color cast removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203945/automatic-enhancement-of-scanned-images) based on [[1](http://www.ivl.disco.unimib.it/papers2003/Color%20BalancingPR.pdf)], which seem like a robust, simple and yet well-performing method. To avoid removing an intrinsic cast by a predominant color such as large regions of vegetation, or water, they use a method of image annotation described by [[2](http://www.ivl.disco.unimib.it/papers2003/IntImgV04%20-%20ImageAnnotationUsingSvm.pdf)].

The color cast detector use a multiclass support vector machine to classify image regions as sky, skin, vegetation, water or other. My problem is that [[2](http://www.ivl.disco.unimib.it/papers2003/IntImgV04%20-%20ImageAnnotationUsingSvm.pdf)] only describes the method, they do not include the parameters of the hyperplanes resulting from training the SVM. Training a new SVM is way out of my scope, but I haven't found any similar works including ready-to-use data. I would really appreciate one of the following:

A. A set of hyperplane parameters resulting from training using the method in [[2](http://www.ivl.disco.unimib.it/papers2003/IntImgV04%20-%20ImageAnnotationUsingSvm.pdf)].

B. Some other image annotation method for sky/skin/vegetation/water, including trained parameters or not requiring training.

C. Some free image database containing annotated regions of sky/skin/vegetation/water, that I can use to train a new SVM using the method in [[2](http://www.ivl.disco.unimib.it/papers2003/IntImgV04%20-%20ImageAnnotationUsingSvm.pdf)].

#### References

1. F. Gasparini and R. Schettini "[Color Balancing of Digital Photos Using Simple Image Statistics](http://www.ivl.disco.unimib.it/papers2003/Color%20BalancingPR.pdf)"
2. C. Cusano, G. Ciocca and R. Schettini "[Image annotation using SVM](http://www.ivl.disco.unimib.it/papers2003/IntImgV04%20-%20ImageAnnotationUsingSvm.pdf)"

Comment: Have you asked the authors of [2] for their model?

Comment: Well, actually no. :-) I just assumed they had some reason for not including it in their paper, but it sure won't hurt to ask. I'll contact them now.

Comment: In order to stop adding problems to your life (:)), my recommendation is simpler: ask the authors of the first paper for the code they used.  It might take some time to get a response, but I don't see why they wouldn't share it. These authors also have at least another paper on this subject, where they combine multiple methods to remove color cast. If you find the reference 1 insufficient, you could go for this one and ask for the code again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer from one of the authors, they don't have any code or data left. Instead he  pointed me to [colorconstancy.com](http://colorconstancy.com/), which contains links to both source code and different image databases. He also mentioned [web.mit.edu/torralba/www/](http://web.mit.edu/torralba/www/), containing an annotated image database that I will use for training the algorithm.