# How to convert a component from HSV to RGB and viceversa

Tags: opencv, rgb, hsv

I have to convert a component color from `HSV` to `RGB` and viceversa in OpenCV.

For example if I have the vector `hsvcomponent = { 30, 80, 100 }` I want the same color in `RGB`

How can I do this in OpenCV? I know that opencv has the `cvtColor` with `CV_BGR2HSV` but this function works with images. I want something simpler.

What can I do?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html#how-to-find-hsv-values-to-track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution to my problem:

```
cv::Vec3b ConvertColor( cv::Vec3b src, int code, int dstCn )
{
    cv::Mat srcMat(1, 1, CV_8UC3 );
    *srcMat.ptr< cv::Vec3b >( 0 ) = src;

    cv::Mat resMat;
    cv::cvtColor( srcMat, resMat, code, dstCn );

    return *resMat.ptr< cv::Vec3b >( 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no implemented function that I know of in OpenCV, but I suggest you should check this out: [How to change RGB color to HSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359612/how-to-change-rgb-color-to-hsv/637025#637025)